# How should a message queue consumer impersonate a user in Identity Server 3 in a microservices environment?

Tags: windows-services, microservices, message-queue, openid-connect, identityserver3

We have a microservices environment using Identity Server 3. Identity is provided to http microservices via bearer tokens in the authorisation http header, where the token is a JWT. That JWT usually represents a logged in end user, but it can also sometimes represent a system user that has authenticated via client credentials flow.

Messages are published on a queue (RabbitMQ) by these microservices, to be processed asynchronously. Currently, we have a windows service which consumes those messages. It authenticates as a system user with client credentials, and sends that JWT in the auth header to other http microservices.

We would like to maintain the identity of the user that publishes the messages throughout the flow, including within the machine-to-machine (m2m) communication when a message is consumed from the queue and when that consumer calls other microservices. Ie, when Service A (which was provided with a JWT) publishes a message to the queue, then the windows service should be able to impersonate the user represented in Service A's JWT, and should be able to provide a JWT representing that same user when calling Service B.

```
Service A (running as alice) --> RMQ 
RMQ <-- Win Service (running as alice) --> Service B (running as alice)
```

Only clients with the correct claim should be able to impersonate a user in this way.

Which flow should I use in order to return the JWT to the Windows Service and how should this be achieved in Identity Server 3? I've managed to generate the JWT using Resource Owner flow, passing in a dummy username and password (overriding `AuthenticateLocalAsync`), although I've not yet attempted to check that the Win Service's client has a valid claim to impersonate. Or should this be a custom flow, implementing `ICustomGrantValidator`? Perhaps client credentials flow can be used?

Note that the original JWT can be provided with the message, or just the user id itself. The original JWT may have expired, which is why the windows service has to re-authenticate in some way.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is you want to propagate authenticated identities through a distributed architecture that includes async messaging via RabbitMQ message broker.

When you send/publish messages to RabbitMQ you might consider including the ACCESS/BEARER TOKEN in the message headers i.e. similar to how ACCESS/BEARER TOKENS are included in HTTP headers for calls to protected HTTP routes. Alternatively if you're feeling a bit lazy, you could just have the ACCESS/BEARER TOKEN directly on the message payload. Your async (Windows service) consumer could validate the JWT on it's way through or it might just pass it through on the subsequent HTTP requests to protected routes of 'other http microservices'.

I'm not sure if you're question about 'which flow should I use' is relevant as presumably the user is already authenticated (via one of the OIDC/authN flows e.g. authentication code grant, implicit, ROPC...) and you're just looking to propagate the JWT through the distributed architecture for authZ purposes...

In terms of sending custom message headers, I have done this with RabbitMQ and MassTransit, but it was for (OpenTracing) trace Id propagation between asynchronous message broker operations. Repo is on GitHub [here](https://github.com/yesmarket/MassTransit.OpenTracing) - might give you some ideas about how to achieve this...

**[edit]** following clarification below:

Below are some options I can think of - each one comes with some security implications:

1. Give the async (windows service) consumer the JWT signing key. If
   you go down this path it probably makes more sense to use symmetric
   signing of JWTs - any service with the symmetric key would be able
   to re-create JWTs. You could probably still achieve the same result
   with asymmetric signing by sharing the private key, but (IMO) the
   private key should be only be known to the authorization server (when using asymmetric signing).
2. When the user authenticates, request a refresh token by adding
   `offline_access` to the list of scopes specified on the /token
   endpoint. You could then pass the refresh token through to the async
   (windows service) consumer, which would be able to use the refresh
   token to obtain a new access token if the previous one has expired (or just get a new one each time).
   There's probably some security considerations that you'd need to
   think about before going down this path.
3. Increase the timeout
   duration of the access tokens so that there's enough time for the
   async (windows service) consumer to handle the requests. Not sure if
   this is viable for your scenario, but would be the easiest option.

Comment: Yes, propogating the jwt is the obvious solution, however, due to the async nature of queues, the jwt may well have expired; hence the need to re-authenticate somehow. i've updated to the question to make this clearere.

Comment: unfortunately we can't generate a refresh token as we are using implicit flow (the user's client is an SPA). and increasing the timeout is not going to be possible due to our security restrictions.

Comment: @darasd if you can't do refresh token, validate only issuer, signature, audience... and forget about expiration, just accept any

Answer (score 0):

JWT is all about having a limited lifetime such that if the token got stolen the length of time systems would be exposed would atleast be limited.

The "refresh token" is how you allow users to renew an access token without having to re-authenticate.

If you can't send the refresh token, with the JWT, then the downstream systems (your windows service) have no way to "renew" this JWT on behalf of a user.

- So increase its expiry time so it doesn't expire during your async flows.

If refresh token, or increasing the expiry time is not possible for you, then you are left with the quandry of how to allow your downstream system to renew an expired JWT without a refresh token - if you think about your downstream system as a hacker that stole the JWT, you can see why the OAUTH spec would be hesitant to cater towards this. So we must ask:-

- Do you really need to renew the token, or can other systems accept an  expired JWT

  - Forced into this situation, I would be tempted to forward the expired JWT but it would involve modifications to the systems that you are sending the expired JWT too, as a means to authenticate - those systems would have to have some logic to work out when and when not to validate the expiry of the JWT. For example, if they can tell the inbound request is from an internal system (or from your windows service) - then perhaps they only check the signature of the JWT and not the expiry.

    - In these applications, aauthentication schemes can usually be combined so for example, they can first authenticate based on client certificate or something that identifies the windows service as the caller. However then they also authenticate based on presence of JWT,  at that point the current calller is aalready known as the windows service, so when they authenticate the JWT they can have logic not to validate the expiry of the JWT.
- Another possibility but horrid, is that prior to putting the JWT in the message, you also place the user's credentials needed to re-authenticate via some oauth flow in the message (assuming you can access them). If the JWT token expires you will re-authenticate on behalf of the user to get a new one, using those credentials